# Can Dagger-2 constructor injection be overridden for testing?

Tags: android, dagger-2

I am using Dagger 2, and I'm trying to understand how to use different configuration for testing.
If I use field injection, I can swap my Modules with fake Modules.
But for classes that have constructor injection, I can't figure out how to do it.
So, is this a reason to avoid constructor annotation? or is there a way to exchange such a class with a fake?

Comment: No, you should be avoiding field injection unless the object is being created by a library that does not use dagger.  How are you having trouble faking modules for  constructor injection?  It should be identical.

Comment: lets say I have class X with constructor injection. and some other class Y that depends on X. I want to have a testing setup that uses FakeX. but because X constructor is annotated with inject, dagger will pick it up. What am I missing here?